# Run a script from anywhere

Tags: linux, shell, shell-scripting

I have a script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "$(dirname $(readlink -e $1))/$(basename $1)"
```

that sits here: `/home/myuser/bin/abspath.sh` which has execute permissions.

If I run `echo $PATH` I get the following: `/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/home/myuser/bin`

I wish to be able to, from any directory, call `abspath <some_path_here>` and it call my script. I am using bash, what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You want to type `abspath`, but the program is named `abspath.sh`. The problem is not regarding whether it is in the PATH, but the fact that you are simply not using its name to call it.

You have two options:

1. Type `abspath.sh` instead.
2. Rename the program to `abspath`.

Comment: ... Or create a simlink: `cd $HOME/bin ; ln -s abspath.sh abspath`. This let you keep the correct extension for the script and having a tool named as you like. (You could in some futur, replace your shell script by a python script, for sample...)

Comment: Or create an alias.

Answer (score 6):

This code is small enough that I would code it as a shell function:

```
abspath() {
    echo "$(dirname "$(readlink -e "$1")")/$(basename "$1")" 
}
```

And yes you do want all those quotes.

Answer (score 4):

set an alias by adding your command in .bashrc file.

```
alias abspath='sh /home/myuser/bin/abspath.sh'
```

And don't forget to source the file.

Comment: Why would you want sudo here?

Comment: I would down vote if I had enough reputation because using sudo unnecessarily is just plain wrong. It seems that some people automatically use sudo for everything instead of learning when and why it's needed.

Comment: Agreed with you guys. And I know When to use sudo. I didn't see the whole questions.

Answer (score 2):

I would rename your bash script to `abspath` then move it to the `bin` directory. You'll be ablet to call `abspath` from anywhere then

Answer (score 0):

A 3rd option is to create an alias called abspath that points to your abspath.sh script.

Comment: Not needed if fixed as the accepted solution explains, also quite convoluted and it actually hides a problem rather than addressing it.

Comment: Not worth arguing, but it goes without saying that if you solve it with one solution, you don't need to apply another solution. Yes this is a bandaid solution and referring directly to the shell script is a more ideal fix.